# Is/were there cases of hazing and violence against younger conscripts in armies of Arabic countries?

Tags: military

Is/were there cases of hazing and violence against younger conscripts in armies of Arabic countries?

It is often advertised in the media that there are no such things in Israeli army, but what about their neighbors?

Comment: Don't believe propaganda, from any side. There is definitely hazing in the Israeli Defence Forces, though it's usually not too harsh by American standards.

Comment: @Carmi - It's probably friendly pats on the head by USSR standards :)  At least I don't recall hearing about people dying from it which DID happen in USSR, quite frequently.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely impossible to answer.

You don't seriously think that a country with iron-fisted control of the media would allow news of something like that to be spread even if it did happen?

For a good example, consider USSR.

Hazing ("dedovschina") was a way of life in the army there, but wasn't exactly well publicized news till 1986 or so.

Comment: It is known that hazing appeared in the USSR about 1967. I think that not all Arab countries have "iron" control of all media, especially now, with Internet. It seems the Arabs do not avoid army service which suggests that there is no that much hazing. Possibly they have clannishness instead.

Comment: As far as Arabs not avoiding army service, again, do you expect detailed reports on the phenomena from Syrian government?

Comment: I would like any accounts, not only from the government.

Comment: Russian Wiki lists cases of hazing as far back as 19th century, including in elite academies. First case post-1917 is listed as 1919. The criminal element recruitment started in 1940s, though 1967 was an extra level of that/